# Doesn't show jsf elements

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, jboss7.x

I made basic dynamic web project with only one page index.xhtml (eclipse juno 4.2 + JBoss AS 7.1). When i run my webpage the browser display only html elements not jsf. My index.xhtml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
push the button:
<button>ok</button>
<h:button value="not ok"></h:button>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see only "ok" button.
When I start my server (standalone) I have warns:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-3) JSF1069: Disabling the JSF 2.0 Facelets ViewHandler as an older FaceletViewHandler, com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler, has been explicitly configured. If this is not desired behavior, remove the older FaceletViewHandler and library from your application.
```

Had anybody the same problem? I make mistake or the ide or server has some bugs?
Thanks for help.

I have got another problem. I want to add library primafaces. I right click on the project then Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add and the .jar is showing in managment window but library doesnt appear in files hierarchy (WEB-INF/lib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webapp's runtime classpath is a mess. The last warning in your log is already the whole answer:

> JSF1069: Disabling the JSF 2.0 Facelets ViewHandler as an older FaceletViewHandler, com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler, has been explicitly configured. If this is not desired behavior, remove the older FaceletViewHandler and library from your application.

You've for some reason a `jsf-facelets.jar` file from Facelets 1.x (as identified by `com.sun.facelets` package) in your webapp's runtime classpath while you're using JSF 2.0 which by itself already has Facelets 2.x packaged (as identified by `com.sun.faces.facelets` package).

Get rid of `jsf-facelets.jar` and any other JSF 1.x related artifacts in your webapp's runtime classpath (among others covered by the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder). Stop reading JSF 1.x targeted books/tutorials/resources and head to JSF 2.x ones. On JSF 2.x, many many things are done differently, so relying on JSF 1.x resources would only end up in confusion and trouble.

On JBoss 7, which already ships with JSF 2.x bundled, you do not need any JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`. You do also not need to put anything in `faces-config.xml`. If you're using JSF 2.1 and rely on default URL mapping of `*.jsf`, then you do also not need to put anything in `web.xml`. So both files can effectively be kept empty.